# Importing Account Hierarchy from one salesforce to another salesforce instance

Tags: data, import

I am facing an issue while importing account records as an insert operation using data loader.

The issue is i am getting an error message

> insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: *****************.

The reason seems account and parent account have lookup() relation and hence parent id must be present in the system before inserting the account record.

My question is how to handle the parent/child in mapping and insert in one short instead first import parent account and then child account.
Anybody has a suggestion please share

Answer (score 0):

You can't populate the id fields in an org. Try adding an external Id field and a parent external Id field.   Make sure they are populated unique on the external id field but not the parent external Id field.  You could just copy the Id  fields directly over to these if you want.   After they are all in the database, write a script to update the lookup fields based off of the extremely ids .